# Powershell: Recursive script call

Tags: powershell, recursion

I have the following two scripts:

```
### main.ps1
. .\inner.ps1 $args[0] $myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
echo "second call"
Write-Host -NoNewLine "Press any key to continue..."
$null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
```

and

```
### inner.ps1
if( $($args[0]) -ne "secondRun") {
    echo "first"
    echo  $($args[1])
    & $($args[1]) "secondRun"
    exit    
}
```

The `exit` command in `inner.ps1` does not exit from the caller script `main.ps1`, so I hit twice the *second call* code.

Can I exit from the caller too?
How can I obtain proper recursion?
I would like to put all/most of the burden of recursion in `inner.ps1` and keep `main.ps1` as clean as possible, which means avoiding adding in `main.ps1` a line like:

```
if( $($args[0]) -ne "secondRun") {exit;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Even with dot-sourcing (`.`), a script cannot instruct its *caller* to `exit`**, so in your current setup you need *some* conditional in `main.ps1` that checks for the need to exit after the `. .\inner.ps1` call.

<sup>Given that helper script `inner.ps1` is being dot-sourced and can therefore modify the environment of the caller, `main.ps1`, one wonders why *recursion* is necessary altogether.

The remainder of this answer accepts the premise of the question, however.</sup>

The OP himself came up with [a solution that encapsulates the recursive-invocation details inside `inner.ps1`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41901201/45375), but the problem is that using the *success stream* (the regular output stream) to send control information - `$TRUE` or `$FALSE` - means that the `if` statement that checks that information (`if (. .\inner.ps1) ...`) *consumes* the regular output from `main1.ps1` and therefore *suppresses* it.<sup>[1]</sup>

In other words: **the approach only works if `main.ps1` happens to produce no output at all, or the caller happens not to care what `main.ps1` outputs**.

The **solution is to base the control flow on *exit codes*** (which PowerShell reflects in automatic variable `$LASTEXITCODE`):

```
### inner.ps1

if(-not $__inner_already_recursed) {

  'inner: reinvoking main...'
  $__inner_already_recursed=$true  # set flag to indicate that recursion has happened
  . $myInvocation.ScriptName       # re-invoke main.ps1

  exit 0 # Signal need to continue execution with $LASTEXITCODE 0

} else {

  'inner: not reinvoking...'  
  exit 1 # Signal that this is already the 2nd invocation.

}
```

and:

```
### main.ps1

'main: entering'

# Call the helper script that performs the recursive invocation.
. .\inner.ps1
if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 1) { exit }  # 1 means previously already reinvoked -> exit

# We only get here once, in the recursive invocation.
'main: should only get here once'
```

As the OP states, the auxiliary variable used to maintain the recursive-invocation state in `inner.ps1` must not preexist (or at least not with a truthy value), so its name - `$__inner_already_recursed` - was chosen to minimize that risk.

---

<sup>[1] `Write-Host` calls aren't affected, because they print directly to the console, but their output can neither be captured nor sent through the pipeline.

  (With additional effort, you could in PSv5+, but that's generally ill-advised and not helpful here.)</sup>

Comment: So much effort. Nice weekend friendly user :)